# Pandas series vectorized text processing

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to improve my Pandas code using vectorized operations. So let's say I have a simple DataFrame with one text column which may contain urls.

```
       Column1
0  hello http://www.google.com
1  bye www.mail.com www.docs.google.com/index
   ...
```

At this moment I am iterating the rows and applying the following substitution:

```
s = re.sub('https*://[\w\.]+\.com[\w=*/\-]+|https*://[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com/[\w/\-]+',lambda x: re.findall('(?<=\://)[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com', x.group())[0], s)
```

The expected output should be:

```
       Column1
0  hello google.com
1  bye mail.com docs.google.com
   ...
```

Is it possible to do this the whole series at a time?

Comment: so you just want to extract the website names? what is the expected output?

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look above

Comment: Are you currently using `pd.Series.apply`?

Comment: please show the actual code you are using currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try an error I have found a valid solution. It's far from being efficient but at this moment I need something that works, I will try to optimize it in a close future and update the post.

```
def replace_url(text):
    pat = '(([https?://]*[www\.]*)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?)'
    urls = re.findall(pat, text)

    for url in urls:
        text = text.replace(url[0], url[2])

    return text

df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(replace_url)
```

Thanks to @killerT2333 he gave me some intuition of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

wih the example you give, you can use `str.replace()`:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace('http|https|://|www.','') \ 
                              #replace some patterm by nothing
                              .str.replace('.com/[\w/\-]+','.com') 
                              # replace specific pattern by other specific pattern
```

Then if it does not fit all your criteria, you can add more `.str.replace()` with the one you need

EDIT: after looking at the [documentation of Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) it's equivalent to `re.sub()` so you can do:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace('https*://[\w\.]+\.com[\w=*/\-]+|https*://[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com/[\w/\-]+',
                                          lambda x: re.findall('(?<=\://)[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com', x.group())[0])
```

Inside, the parameters are the same than in your `re.sub()` of your question. But you don't really get your expected output, you keep the 'www.' with this.

Comment: Mmm... interesting. I will have a look at this and try to see what is going on

Comment: I am sorry but although your answer is kind of useful I think it did not solve my question so I will not accept it yet

Comment: @m33n can you tell me in what it does not solve the question, maybe I can help :) The first method is a vectorize way to do the job. The second way too except the regex pattern is not good for your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your logic and your code for the substitution, you can do it as follow:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import re

    d = {'Column1': ["hello http://www.google.com", "bye www.mail.com www.docs.google.com/index"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


    f = lambda s : re.sub('https*://[\w\.]+\.com[\w=*/\-]+|https*://[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com/[\w/\-]+',lambda x: re.findall('(?<=\://)[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com', x.group())[0], s)


    print(df["Column1"].apply(f))
```

Comment: This was to show how to apply a function to a DataFrame as you have asked, otherwise the method proposed by Ben T is also completely valid

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def replace_url(text):
    """
    Define the beginning of a url in a regex and replace any input text with an empty string using the regex
    INPUT: text (type = string)
    OUTPUT: text (type = string)
    """
    url_reg = re.compile(r"(http(s)?|www).*(\.)")
    return re.sub(url_reg, "", text)

df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(replace_url)
```

Here, we have the function clearly defined (replace the beginning of urls), then we apply it in a vectorised way to the entire column of the dataframe. This method is usually faster than pandas replace method, although I haven’t timed it here so I cannot be certain in this case.

Comment: Apply methods are not vectorized. And str.replace() are indeed vectorized methods...